# Gitlab: no user or key was provided

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I tried to push the master branch from a client to a server which installed the gitlab. However, I got the following error info:

```
[root@warehouse git-sample]# git push origin master
git@192.168.7.82's password: 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 224 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: No user or key was provided.
To git@192.168.7.82:ite-pon/git-sample.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@192.168.7.82:ite-pon/git-sample.git'
```

It looks like the gitlab setup a pre-receive hook into the project, but blocked the push operation.

Does anybody has any idea to deal with this issue? Thx~ :)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Below are the detail configuration and information both for server and client:

**Server: GitLab & Git & Repository Info**

```
[root@warehouse git-sample.git]# pwd
/opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/repositories/ite-pon/git-sample.git
```

1. Gitlab record the client's ssh pub key (no enough reputation to send
   img :()
2. Setup Administrator (client user) as Master for this project, and as
       Owner for the domain.

**Server: Configuration**

```
[root@warehouse repositories]# grep git /etc/passwd
git:x:502:502:Git:/opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/repositories:/opt/gitlab/git/bin/git-shell
```

**Client: Workspace Info**

```
[root@warehouse git-sample]# pwd
/root/workspaces/git-sample/git-sample
[root@warehouse git-sample]# ls
readme.txt
[root@warehouse git-sample]# git branch
  dev
* master
[root@warehouse git-sample]# git remote -v
origin  git@192.168.7.82:ite-pon/git-sample.git (fetch)
origin  git@192.168.7.82:ite-pon/git-sample.git (push)
```

**Client: SSH & Git Info**

```
[root@warehouse git-sample]# git config --global user.name
Administrator
[root@warehouse git-sample]# git config --global user.email
admin@gitlab.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
[root@warehouse git-sample.git]# ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 413 7月   1 15:51 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: How did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you reached the bug that just documented on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2156 -- the workaround being to remove the key from the authorized_keys files on the server.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. The workaround in the link fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

This helped to me. This command take all keys from database and update records in authorized_keys file.

For Omnibus-packages:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup
```

For installations from source:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-file